# How to insert the image in RawHTMLBlock field i.e. blocks.RawHTMLBlock(icon='code', label='HTML')

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to insert image in `blocks.RawHTMLBlock()` but its not happening. Please, anyone knows how to do this?
my `models.py` is

```
wagtail.core.blocks.RawHTMLBlock

 body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock(icon='image')),
        ('rich_text', blocks.RichTextBlock(icon='doc-full', label='Rich Text')),
        ('html', blocks.RawHTMLBlock(icon='code', label='HTML', image='image')),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RawHTMLBlock` is used to input HTML code to be output directly onto the page with no further handling from Wagtail. Therefore, to output an image, use the standard HTML tag: `<img src="...">`.

Comment: I used this tag but its not working `<img class="responsive"  src="{% static "images/features/employee-mass-communication-ghr.png" %}" alt="Employee Alerts"/>`

Comment: You can't use Django template tags such as `{% static %}` within a RawHTMLBlock - it has to be pure HTML.